# Kafka Stream failed to rebalance on startup

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to run a Kafka stream application and I'm running into the following exception when kafka stream starts.

Here the configurations that I'm using on Kafka 0.10.1

```
final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "some app id");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "some app id");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_CONFIG, "localhost:2181");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde");
```

The exception that I'm getting.

```
Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Failed to rebalance
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:410)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:242)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:360)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:157)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.init(RocksDBStore.java:163)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.init(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:85)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.init(CachingKeyValueStore.java:62)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.initializeStateStores(AbstractTask.java:81)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:120)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStreamTask(StreamThread.java:633)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:660)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$100(StreamThread.java:69)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:124)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:228)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:313)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:277)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:259)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1013)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:979)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:407)
... 1 more
```

Seems like I need to set `state.dir` but that doesn't seem to work. By default on Kafka 0.10.1, it already defaults to `/tmp/kafka-streams`. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: No idea atm (I would recommend to run this in an IDE and set a breakpoint to debug), but I would highly recommend to use a new version anyway. Note, you don't need to upgrade brokers for this if you don't want, as Streams API is backward compatible to older brokers: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/upgrade-guide.html#compatibility

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I managed to figure it out. I was using KTable instead of KStream. It looks like the compatibility matrix doesn't fully support 0.10.1 with Streams API 0.11 but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Not sure what you mean...?. BtwL there is only one feature that is not supported for Streams 0.11 with older brokers -- should not be a big deal -- would still recommend to use Streams API 0.11 (or 1.0.0 that will be released soon) as it contains a lot of critical bug fixes and other new features that will make your life much easier. Just saying.